# height shifted to top and width unchanging of div in flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex box where are there are four `divs`. I want to decrease the height of second div by 50%, the height has become 50% but it's shifted to top of the flex box.

Then I want the width of fourth div to be 25% of the container but its not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
      height: 500px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    .flex-container>div {
      background-color: DodgerBlue;
      color: white;
      width: 100px;
      margin: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 75px;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    .antarik {
      height: 50%;
    }
    
    .details {
      width: 25%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <h1>The align-self Property</h1>
  </p>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div class="antarik">2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div class="details">4</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: margin-top:auto to that div?

Comment: @TemaniAfif not working `.antarik
{
  margin-top:auto
  height: 50%;
}`

Comment: `div.antarik {   margin-top:auto   height: 50%; }` OR align-self:flex-end

Comment: Add `!important` to `margin-top: auto !important;` it gets overwritten by `margin: 10px;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To align your antarik div, you can use `align-self` - use `flex-end` to make it shift to the bottom, or `center` for it in the middle

For your last div, use `flex-basis` instead of width

And finally, remove the p tag around the h1 (it is invalid html)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.antarik {
  height: 50%;
  align-self:flex-end;
}

.details {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}
```

```html
<h1>The align-self Property</h1>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div class="antarik">2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div class="details">4</div>
</div>
```